# OpenCV, Android and JNI

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm developing a Android application which JNI code and this code makes use of OpenCV library.

The .c class of JNI code is "**sintetica.c**":

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "sintetica.h"

#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

jint  Java_com_example_imagen3d_Imagen3DActivity_sintetica(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jint argc, jchar *argv[]) {

...

    return 0;

}
```

The **Android.mk** file :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC

include /home/vmg/workspace/android/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE :=sintetica
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=sintetica.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The **Application.mk** file :

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

And the **Java class**:

```
![public class Imagen3DActivity  extends Activity {
       ...
    public native int Java_com_example_imagen3d_Imagen3DActivity_sintetica(int argc, char argv\[\]);   
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("sintetica");
    }  
}]
```

I'm a Linux user and I'm using Eclipse Juno and Opencv 2.4.5, although for the .c class i used OpenCV library of linux repositories and i don't know what version is it.

A part of the errors which happen is as follows:

```
20:10:55 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Imagen3D ****
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/ndk-build 
SharedLibrary  : libsintetica.so
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0x86): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0x94): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0xa4): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0x11c): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0x9c4): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0xb78): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0x2058): error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
/home/vmg/android/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_photo.a(inpaint.cpp.o): in function cvInpaint:inpaint.cpp(.text.cvInpaint+0x2146): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but your `native` method in Java code (only in Java code) should definately be named `sintetica` instead of current long one.